# How hard is the glass on Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I haven't got a screen protector for my MacBook Pro, and I am wondering just how easy it is to get a scratch on it? Is it using the Gorilla Glass like the iPad? If so, I might consider not getting a screen protector at all.

Anyone with some experience?

Update:

After a year of testing, albeit I've replaced the upper component including display and the casing, I will say it is reasonably strong. Mine is the first-generation one, but I would imagine all future model is just as good.

Comment: I'd say under normal circumstances you wouldn't get any scratches on it, but what's normal for me might not be for you.

Comment: @Gerry sounds like you got a MBP your own. Is its back and front easily scratched under "normal circumstances". (Let's take that our definition on normal circumstances is the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on: http://www.anandtech.com/show/5998/macbook-pro-retina-display-analysis
the glass is not the same as on the usual MBP but instead created using two layers of glass.

But the thing is the new Retina MBP does not have the cover glass. That does mean that if you scratch it in a way you are scratching the real LCD and not just a cover glass which would be the case if you scrach the display on a MBP.

Hope you can decide from that whether or not you should use a screen protector.

Comment: So, if I get a scratch on it, I'm damaging the panel? And there's no glass to scratch on? But from the link you gave me, it does look like it has a glass on top of the panel. More importantly, I still got glare, which I think LCD panel doesn't do.

Comment: No, there's still a layer between you and the actual LCD elements, it's just at there's one fewer than in the non-retina model.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older version macbook pro. The anti glare version which also does not has this glass glossy layer. 
Got this MBP in early 2011 and been using it daily. In and out my bag, even dropped it 2 times and there are bumbs along the body. But the screen is still in perfect condition. Not a single scratch and I even had people pointing with paws on my screen :(

So yeah this is not exactly the new retina screen but I think you can say that you don't need the screen protector.